Sudden appearance of audio problems under Windows 10. How can I solve this?
I've been using a desktop computer for many years without audio problems. Last time I used the audio was a few days ago. Never a problem. Today, no program can deliver audio output to my headphones. The VLC player crashes. The Windows Media Player gives me this message:

I also get this error:

And Firefox, while it appears to play YouTube videos just fine doesn't have any audio reaching my headphones.
I also plugged in an AmazonBasics microphone/headphone combo device that plugs into a USB port. Completely different device, uses USB instead of the motherboard line-out jack, and I also get the same message from the Media Player that shows up above. (This unit works fine on other laptops I have here, as well as other desktops. So I know it works okay.)
I've done the usual:

Re-booted the Windows 10 desktop computer.
Installed the latest Windows 10 software updates from Microsoft. (There were a few pending at the time. No longer.)
Uninstalled the audio drivers and re-installed them -- both for the motherboard and for the USB microphone combo unit.
Fired up services.msc, located "Windows Audio", stopped it, then started it back up again.
Disabled audio enhancements.
Ensured that the appropriate hardware device was selected as the default device.

This has been quite sudden. Something happened in the last couple days. And re-booting, updating the operating system, etc. -- none of this has resolved the problem.
The "troubleshooter" within Windows went through its own processes and didn't find anything to help out.
So I'm at a bit of a loss right now as what next to try.
And that's my question. What else should I attempt towards a goal of isolating the problem and resolving it?

Have you tested the internal speakers and/or devices other than your headphones? Admittedly this doesn't seem like an issue with the headphones, but it may help narrow down. Also, did any kind of auto-update run that touched anything serious like firmware or BIOS? Could check your BIOS and ensure the on-board audio is set as it should be.

@nannerpuss There is a built-in audio system on the motherboard and it extends out the green (etc.) colored connectors for microphone, line out, etc. All that worked a few days ago. Now I get error messages, with some better-written programs that seem to be able to detect certain audio problems, and no audio at all in cases where the programs do not detect errors. That's why I tried dragging over a completely different system that ties into USB and requires entirely different drivers. Same errors for programs providing errors, same no audio for programs that don't provide errors.

@nannerpuss I know that the stand-alone hardware works well on all the other machines here, this is isolated to this computer. And since the hardware is completely different but presenting the same errors in same circumstances, I'm pretty sure the motherboard audio components are still okay. Or, if the motherboard hardware isn't okay, then perhaps that hardware is interfering and preventing known-good hardware from operating. But it would need to be causing problems even when it is disabled -- because I disable it before testing the known-good stuff.

@nannerpuss To me, this has the feel of a kernel code component error. Something faulty in Windows that isn't at the driver/hardware side and likely isn't at the application system call side. Windows had been downloading, in the background, stuff it wanted to install -- in the few days since I last used the audio. But I prevented its reboot installation step (until today) and haven't installed any application software in months. So... I'm flummoxed.

It sounds like you hit all the right troubleshooting steps already and that you are comfortable doing diagnostic stuff, so I would suggest trying to get some kind of error message or at least an Info level event from Event Viewer. Right-Click your Start button and open it or use Run and 'eventvwr' (will need Admin credentials of course). Make sure you can view all Administration and System level events and recreate the problem in as many ways as you can, with "good" and "bad" sound software, etc. Try to get a device or hardware error.

@nannerpuss That looks like a useful tool. I'm completely unfamiliar with its use, sadly. But here is an example of administrative events in and around the time I was playing before writing up the question. I guess I need to spend some time with this tool and see if I can ferret something useful out, after I learn more about what it does and where it keeps info I might like to see. Thanks!

@nannerpuss  There's also an interesting warning in the middle of those errors (at the same time): The machine-default permission settings do not grant Local Activation permission for the COM Server application with CLSID {C2F03A33-21F5-47FA-B4BB-156362A2F239} and APPID {316CDED5-E4AE-4B15-9113-7055D84DCC97}. Perhaps there is a permission issue.

I am no expert in Event Viewer myself, but those errors (Event ID 131) are related to metadata retrieval from Microsoft servers (WMIS I believe) and shouldn't actually be an issue to worry about. Could be just a timeout during a routine check. The amount and rapidity of them is a bit strange though. As for the CLSID permissions error, those too are fairly common and I have tons of them myself. Honestly my best suggestion would have been a total driver removal and reinstallation and/or a System Restore to a known working point and then you could (cont.)

... then you could say for certain it's hardware failure if it doesn't work with previous known working configuration. This does sound like actual hard/firmware failure to me, assuming all mentioned troubleshooting was already done.

Have you checked out the audio device in Device Manager? I think that's worth a look for sure, assuming it is listed there. If it is listed and doesn't have a warning icon or anything, open the Properties and see if you can move the drivers forward/backward (rollback or update), and inspect the event log from there as well. It will list the most recent reported events from the device.

@nannerpuss Oh, yeah. Of course I went to the device manager. It's the first place I go. That worked like a clock. If I plugged in the USB device I would see it install and show up without any errors. When I unplugged it, it would then disappear properly. Just worked real nice. Drivers were the most updated, no errors flagged. I could read the USB info block, etc.

@nannerpuss  Thanks so much for your thoughts and for the new tool I may yet learn a bit better over time. Appreciated. My last restore point is 20 days ago, so I'd lose too much going there without a fair bit of hand back-up work to pick and choose what I'd need to add back.

Swap headphones. If the others work you have defective headphones.

@JanDoggen The headphones are standard 3.5mm jacks. I have lots of headphones. And these particular ones work, as do the others. Defective headphones is perhaps the most certain thing I can say is not the problem here. They didn't suddenly go bad. Besides, they work fine with the USB microphone setup as the AmazonBasics microphone has its own jack for the headphones and I can easily hear myself talking in the headphones with that unit while it is also jacked into the PC (and doesn't work with play-back there.) PC? No sound. Hardware unit? Sound is fine.

This is typical behavior when the audio driver is in use exclusively.
For example, if i use my DAW, it can claim the audio driver in exclusive mode, and then no other program can play audio to that device. When that happens, the exact same problems happen to me as you describe.
Another case that will yield the same result is when the audio driver itself crashes or otherwise stopped working.
With this information, lets troubleshoot.
Step one, reboot the system. And just to state the blunt obvious: turning off the computer and then back on is not the same as rebooting and will not fix the issue. You need to press start, shutdown, reboot. The reason is Hybrid shutdown, it will close all programs then put the computer in hibernation. This keeps all drivers alive, but also keep any crashed driver in crashed state.
After the reboot, check if things have resolved. If not, reinstall the audio drivers by first uninstalling the drivers, reboot, then install them again. If you don't have drivers you can uninstall through settings, use device manager to remove the device and uninstall the drivers that way.
If this does not fix the issue, it is possible there is a hardware problem. If the soundcard is part of the motherboard, you will need to buy a new sound card as addon. If you have an addon soundcard, you may need to replace it. (Yes, in this case, its an external USB soundcard, I'm just stating it here because others will also find this answer)
If none of this seems to work, try to pinpoint the date when this started to happen, and see if Windows Updates were installed around that date. It may be a bug in one of the updates, or maybe the driver got updated then.
Lastly, for this specific question: If your computer has a soundcard on the motherboard, unplug any USB soundcards, reboot the system, install drivers for the soundcard on the motherboard if you haven't done that, and test if that works. Once you get a working audio system, plug one external sound device in and test again, and do this for all devices until one breaks the system again or it works normally. If at some point it breaks, redo these steps, but then not plug in that one failing device and see if it works for all others, or that other devices also crash the audio service. I expect that one audio driver is crashing the service, so once you isolate which audio driver it is, uninstall the audio driver and see if you can find an older driver.
Also, it may actually work if you run sfc /scannow

Thanks for taking your time here. I appreciate it very much. I don't have time right now to go through your process, but I will and I'll write back about it. I also like the sfc option. I'll try that, too. Some of the things you write I can discount, as I've already covered them (and can discuss later.) But some of what you write is worth the trouble. So thanks so much!! I'll give it a shot. I'll give this a +1 right now, though. I already appreciate the trouble and your thoughts. So that's a given.

I have read the comments. I have also written this as a general answer for others who find your question with a similar issue. :) So no worries.
